# Is there a PHP ethereum API or SDK?

Tags: ether

Please let me know if there is a PHP ethereum API or SDK, with the following requirements:

1. The project must be currently maintained. Don't send a link to a project that has not been updated in 2 years.
2. I don't want to open any additional ports on my Linux server.
3. I need to add transactions to the Ropsten Testnet.
4. There can't be any limits to requests (such as 200 requests per hour), and there can't be a monthly fee.
5. It must be a stable, proven API or SDK that will not be terminated in the near future.

Comment: Try [Ethereum-PHP](https://github.com/digitaldonkey/ethereum-php). Its not feature complete yet, but sponsored by ConsenSys and constantly worked on.
The problem is when you want to WRITE to the blockchain you need to have a Ethereum node with a private key, which I wouldn't recommend.